# "Attention needed" error uploading app to Windows Store, but no error description displayed

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, xap, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to upload an update of my app to Windows Store. It never passes the "Certification" stage. After a while it shows error: "Attention needed", but when I click on it there are no errors displayed. How can I access a report of the errors?

I tried Windows App Cert Kit, but it doesn't run on my Windows 10 desktop. And the Windows 10 version doesn't work with 8.0 XAP files.

Comment: Does it allow you to submit the app but fails when running the automated tests?  Did you update the apps icon and splash screen?   Did you submit a xap compiled in release mode?

Comment: I am able to submit to the store and, after 1 our or so, it shows the "Attention needed" error. A later time it was stuck on "Certification" for 24 hours and I had to cancel it. I have updated the splash screen (but its filename). It is the XAP that Phonegap Build generates, so I guess it is in release mode. Is there any log I can check on Windows Store?

Comment: if you go to dev.windows.com and go to your dashboard I would expect a report to be on the page for the app you submitted.  If you can not find one open a support ticket with microsoft to find out what is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the similar case recently. In my cases, **'Attention needed'** was shown at certification phase. But **no error reports were shown**. Then, I noticed that my 'Submission N' page (see the screen capture below) have 'submit' button. I just clicked it to resubmit... the process was resumed, then, my app was published to the store successfully.

[image]